# Data Bind in ASP.Net for Dropdown box

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have to get the Values ( A,B,C,D) from a table Named as dbo.Names into a dropdown box from SQL Server.I had done it manually ,but how to i achieve the same using select statement from table..???or if i have to select from stored procedure where a variable in containing the values???

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-4 lhs-form-box" style="padding: 10px; height: 247px;">
        <div class="form-group" style="width: 87%; float: left;">
            <label for="sel1">ITEM</label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_QU" runat="server" class="form-control">
                <asp:ListItem Text="A" Value="A"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="B" Value="B"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="C" Value="C></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="D" Value="D"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <span>
            <img src="info.png" style="margin: 31px 0px 0px 5px">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any database access already in your application? Are you using ADO.NET? Entity Framework? nHibernate? Linq to SQL?

Comment: I do have a stored procedure which i am using in webpage.I can retreive value from variable as well..any idea..how do i do it??

Comment: You'll need to show your code for that.

Answer (score -1):

```
DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select", ""));
    DropDownList1.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["your connection"].ConnectionString;
    String strQuery = "SELECT ID, Name FROM YourTable";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        DropDownList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Name";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon because links can become broken. Please try to summarize the relevant portions of what is found within the link here. The user can go to that link for more information if need be.

Comment: Updated with Code example. Now you should not give downvote.

Comment: I was the one that downvoted. And I'm leaving it in place for now, because code dump answers are frowned upon. You should provide an explanation describing what the code does and why. And `throw ex;` is an antipattern.

Comment: I didn't give a down vote, and it is up to each user to determine how valuable an answer it is. I could have voted down, and I also could have flagged the answer. However, seeing you were a new user, I wanted to give you a heads up to try and avoid any repercussions.

Comment: @mason-Could you please help me out??

Answer (score -2):

/////
Just Use Asp:Repeater here
///

```
            <div class="col-sm-4 lhs-form-box" style="padding: 10px; height: 247px;">
                <div class="form-group" style="width: 87%; float: left;">
                    <label for="sel1">ITEM</label>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptNames" runat="server" class="form-control">
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp: Label>
                    </asp: Repeater>
                </div>
                <span>
                    <img src="info.png" style="margin: 31px 0px 0px 5px"></span>

            </div>
```

/////
Just Use Asp:Repeater here

and in your sql query 
select name from yourTable

in code Behind
///

rptNames.DataSource = datatable;// from sql
rptNames.Databind();

Comment: i didn't understand this...can u please elaborate??

Comment: This isn't valid syntax for a repeater. And judging by a question, the data needs to be in a DropDownList, not a repeater. Please pay closer attention to what is being asked and make sure you provide a valid answer in the future. I suggest you delete this answer as it's not relevant.